# FreeRTOS Cross Thread Read

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, multitasking, freertos

Is it safe to have one thread modify an atomic unit (e.g. a char) while the other only reads it?
In an environment that permits this of course, like freertos.

I have been given some code that does just this, it uses a bool (defined as char) as a semaphore, I'm not sure why they didnt use a semaphore just for claritys sake, but then again I cant see the danger in using a char either really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its safe If:

1.Your processors reads a character in single instruction(which is very likely)

2.Your Processor architecture is not such that while executing a instruction external interrupt can change control flow.

3.Point 2 is vaild only if your variable is updated through ISR